# CGAL: Iterate over all vertices of all faces

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I have a SurfaceMesh in CGAL:

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html

I understand how to iterate over each face, as is shown in the examples:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                    Point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point>          Surface_mesh;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::graph_traits<Surface_mesh>::face_descriptor fit, faces(mesh)){
  //do something here
}
```

Here, mesh is a Surface_mesh.  What is not at all clear to me is what a face_descriptor is, and how to use it.  How can one go about accessing the half-edges and vertices of a face when one has a face_descriptor?  In particular, how might one iterate over all vertices of a half-edge, and get their coordinates?

Comment: `mesh.halfedge(fit)` should give you one half-edge to start with. The user manual you link to has an example with `vertices_around_face`. Also search for `point` to get a point...

Comment: Can you please link to or reproduce that example?

Comment: Look at the example https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html#circulators_example which shows how to enumerate the vertices on the boundary of a face

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to, for each face, iterate through the vertices around the face.

Which is what the following code does:

```
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point>    Mesh;
typedef CGAL_Mesh::Face_index        face_descriptor;

int i=0;
BOOST_FOREACH(face_descriptor f, faces(mesh)){
    int j=0;
    CGAL::Vertex_around_face_iterator<Mesh> vbegin, vend;
    for(boost::tie(vbegin, vend) = vertices_around_face(mesh.halfedge(f), mesh);
            vbegin != vend;
            ++vbegin){
        j++;
        std::cout << "jth index of ith face: "<< *vbegin << std::endl;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Boost Graph Library has a concept [`Graph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/Graph.html) that defines `vertex_descriptor` and `edge_descriptor`. They are identifiers for the elements of a graph. In CGAL we extended that to graphs with faces and halfedges.  The concept [`FaceGraph`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/BGL/classFaceGraph.html) explains what you can do with a `face_descriptor`. From this page you can go, via *Refines:*, to the concept [`HalfedgeGraph`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/BGL/classHalfedgeGraph.html)  which tells you what you can do with the other descriptors.

The links go to the online manual of the upcoming version of CGAL, where we improved the documentation concerning the descriptors - so you are not alone.